# If the connected sum of a manifold $M$ with itself gives back $M$, does it imply $M$ is a sphere?

Tags: algebraic-topology, compact-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact, connected, oriented $n$-dimensional manifold without boundary. Suppose that $M\#M\cong M$. Does it imply that $M \cong S^n$?

Sorry if this is a naive question. This is not my area, and I have very few examples of higher dimensional manifolds under my belt, so I wouldn't know how to construct a counter-example!

Comment: $\simeq$ is homeomorphism or homotopic?

Comment: @Sigur Homeomorphism!

Comment: You can also prove it using Eilenberg's swindle. Another remark is that the statement is false in the differentiable category.

Comment: @studiosus Cool! If you'd like to write something up and post it as an answer (even if it's only a partial answer), I'd love to read it. Regards,

Comment: @studiosus:  I, too, would like to see exactly how to use Eilenberg's swindle in this case.  The only uses of it I know are those on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: The swindle argument can be found here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/mazurs-swindle/.

Comment: @Drew:  This is one of the arguments in the wikipedia page as well.  But I do not see how to modify it to work in this case.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Oh, I totally misread the question! Hmm, now I'd like to see it as well

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is true.  More generally, we prove that if $N\sharp M \cong N$ for a single closed orientable manifold $N$, then $M$ is homeomorphic to a sphere.

First, by the classification of compact surfaces, this is true when $N$ and $M$ are surfaces, so we may assume $n=\dim N \geq 3$.

Now, one can apply van Kampen's Theorem to learn that $\pi_1(M\sharp N)\cong \pi_1(M)\ast \pi_1(N)$.  Since $N$ is compact, $\pi_1(N)$ is finitely generated, say with minimal generating set consisting of $r$ generators.  Let $s$ be the minimal number of generators of $\pi_1(M)$.  Then, $r+s$ is the size of the minimal generating set of $\pi_1(M)\ast \pi_1(N) \cong \pi_1(N)$, so $r+s = r$.  Since $r$ is finite, this implies $s = 0$.  Thus, $M$ is simply connected.

Using Mayer-Veitoris, and the fact that $N$ is orientable (assumption) and $M$ is orientable (since it's simply connected), one now sees that $H_i(N)\cong H_i(M\sharp N) \cong H_i(M)\oplus H_i(N)$ for $0< i < n$.  Since the homology groups of $M\sharp N$ and $M$ are finitely generated abelian groups, we can cancel to find that $H_i(M) = 0$ for $0<i<n$.

All this shows that $M$ is a simply connected homology sphere.  The Hurewicz theorem together with Whitehead's theorem now imply $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a sphere.  Finally, the Poincare conjecture then implies that $M$ is homeomorphic to a sphere.

Comment: Very nice! Note that it is not entirely obvious that the minimum number of generators for a free product is the sum of the minimum number of generators for each factor.  See [this paper](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-18/1/12.extract) for a proof.

Comment: Cool stuff Jason, thanks for your answer! I'll leave the question open until tonight (for visibility) and then I'll accept your answer. Again, thank you. Regards,

Comment: @Jim:  I agree it's not obvious.  In fact, an earlier version of this post labeled the argument as "tentative" exactly because of this reason.  I found the result I needed here http://books.google.com/books?id=1LW4s1RDRHQC&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=minimal+presentation+of+a+free+product+of+groups&source=bl&ots=WpBO8WZgHC&sig=xk1y7M8bdiAFrDPn_IPWdtZiVlo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pUqGUoysDMGfkAfl_IDABg&ved=0CF4Q6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=minimal%20presentation%20of%20a%20free%20product%20of%20groups&f=false but then a student came by and I forgot to add it in as a comment ;-)

Comment: I think, the statement about the rank of the free product is called Grushko's theorem.

Comment: Wow, this answer uses some serious heavy artillery.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm quite impressed as well! Also, I wonder when the Poincaré conjecture will start being known as the Perelman theorem...

Comment: @Bruno:  If anything, the Poincare conjecture should be known as the Freedman-Perelman-Smale theorem ;-).

Comment: @Jason: I will take your word for it! I am definitely in no position to attribute credit (except to you, for your nice answer).

Comment: @Bruno:  Well, Perelman did dimension 3, Freedmean did dimension 4, and Smale did 5 and up.  I don't know who to give credit to in 2, perhaps Riemann for his mapping theorem?  (I know very little math history).

Comment: @Jason Ah, that makes sense. I do not know who the classification of orientable surfaces is due to. I suppose that it's been known for a long time by a lot of people, in varying degrees of rigor.