# $M \# M \cong M$ in the noncompact case

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, surgery-theory

I recently saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263751/if-the-connected-sum-a-b-is-homeomorphic-to-s2-then-a-cong-b-cong-s2) question and [its generalisation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568297/if-the-connected-sum-of-a-manifold-m-with-itself-gives-back-m-does-it-imply), and it made me wonder about the non-compact case: is there ever a case when $M \# M \cong M$ for $M$ non-compact?

Clearly this would only ever be the case when $M$ has no holes, but beyond this I cannot think of any conditions that would ensure that such a property holds. Can anyone give me any clues? I would prefer something purely topological, since anything homology is not my strong suit.

Comment: "Clearly this would only ever be the case when $M$ has no holes" or infinitely many holes.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right!

Comment: @Doc:  Would you care to write an answer using Arthur's hint?

Comment: Jason, it doesn't really constitute an answer, that is, I don't know that the statement: "for $M$ non-compact, $M \# M \cong M$ iff either $M$ has no holes or $M$ has infinitely-many holes" is even true..

Comment: @Doc:  (If you put the @ in front of my name, I get pinged - I just now saw your comment to me since Nick's answer bumped this question up).    My point was that Arthur told you exactly why the answer is NO:  If $\Sigma$ is a surface of infinite genus, then $\Sigma\sharp\Sigma \cong \Sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $M$ has a finite number of topological ends (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)), then this cannot be true. Since the number of topological ends of $M \# M$  is twice that of $M$.

An instructive example is as follows: if $M = \mathbb{R}^{2}$, then $M$ has $1$ end and the connected sum $M \# M$ is an infinite cyclinder $S^{1} \times \mathbb{R}$, in this space there are two "ways to travel to infinity" hence this space cannot be homeomorphic to $M$.

We sketch the proof. Denote by $e(X)$ the number of ends of $X$.

To prove the statement in general, Let $K_{n}$ be a sequence of compact subsets such that

1. $K_{n} \subset K_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

2.$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} K_{n} = M$$.

By definition, the number of connected components of $M \setminus K_{n}$ will  be equal to $e(X)$ for $n$ large enough. Let $B$ be a topological ball in $M$, note that there exists $n$ such that $B \subset K_{i}$ for $i \geq n$. By throwing away the first $n$ subsets we may assume that $B \subset K_{i} \forall i$. We perform the connect sum $M \# M$ by gluing two copies of $M$ along $B$

Now the subsets $K_{n} \# K_{n} \subset M \# M$ are nested and  exhaust $M \# M$ (i.e. satisfy conditions 1 and 2 above applied to  $M \# M$) . On the other hand, for $n$ great enough the number of connected components of  $M \# M \setminus K_{n} \# K_{n}$ will be equal to $2e(M)$. We have shown that $e(M \# M) = 2e(M)$

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps the person needed more of an explanation

Comment: I added some more explanation + an example. I hope it is clearer now

Comment: @NickL Maybe someone took issue with "manifolds with infinitely many ends are rather pathological."   Universal covers can easily have infinitely many ends, for example.

Comment: @Kyle Miller. Sure, I guess pathological is not the right word, I removed it.